# Como valido que los números que sean ingresados sean más de 8 (JAVASCRIPT)

Tags: javascript

Estoy haciendo un script el cual cuando escriban el nit, este calcule el dígito de verificación, pero necesito que el usuario ingrese más de 8 caracteres, Como válido que los números que sean ingresados sean más de 8, ya intente con `minlength="8"` en el input text pero no pasa nada, agradezco su ayuda.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      


<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $('#nit').change(function (event) {
                    if(validarSiNumero($('#nit').val())) {
                        $('#nit').val(calcularDigitoVerificacion($('#nit' ).val()));
                    } else {
                        $('#nit').val('');
                    }
                });
            });
 
            function validarSiNumero(numero){
                if(!/^([0-9])*$/.test(numero)) {
                    alert("El valor "+numero+" no es un número");
                    return false;
                } else {
                    return true;
                }
            }            
            
            function calcularDigitoVerificacion(nit) {
                console.log("Entro a  la funcion");
                var sumatoria, digitoNit, longitudNit, DV;
                var arregloPrimos=[];               
                
                //procedimiento
                sumatoria = 0;
                digitoNit = 0;
                longitudNit = nit.length;
                arregloPrimos[1] = 3;
                arregloPrimos[2] = 7;
                arregloPrimos[3] = 13;
                arregloPrimos[4] = 17;
                arregloPrimos[5] = 19;
                arregloPrimos[6] = 23;
                arregloPrimos[7] = 29;
                arregloPrimos[8] = 37;
                arregloPrimos[9] = 41;
                arregloPrimos[10] = 43;
                arregloPrimos[11] = 47;
                arregloPrimos[12] = 53;
                arregloPrimos[13] = 59;
                arregloPrimos[14] = 67;
                arregloPrimos[15] = 71;
                
                console.log("Longitud Nit="+longitudNit);

                for (i = 0; i < longitudNit; i++)
                {
                    digitoNit = (nit.substr(i, 1));
                    sumatoria += (digitoNit * arregloPrimos[longitudNit - i]);
                    console.log("i="+i+" DigitoNit="+digitoNit+" Sumatoria="+sumatoria);
                }

                var modulo = sumatoria % 11;

                if (modulo > 1) {
                    DV = 11 - modulo;
                    return  nit+'-'+DV;
                } else {
                    DV = modulo;
                    return   nit+'-'+DV;
                }
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <label>Nit: </label>
        <input type="text" name"nit"  id="nit" placeholder ="Escribe el Nit"  >
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: En lugar de colocar *contenido de relleno*, edita y explica que llevas hecho y la relación de este código con la duda expuesta por favor, además lee [ask] y realiza el [tour]

Comment: Estoy haciendo un script el cual cuando escriban el nit, este calcule el dígito de verificación, pero necesito que el usuario ingrese más de 8 caracteres, Como válido que los números que sean ingresados sean más de 8, ya intente con minlength="8" en el input text pero no pasa nada, agradezco su ayuda.

Comment: Edita entonces tu pregunta y ofrece esos detalles en la misma

Answer (score 0):

Dado que quieres comprobar si el valor insertado en el campo de texto tiene una longitud mínima de 8, puedes añadir al `if` la comprobación de dicha longitud.

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $('#nit').change(function (event) {
                    if(validarSiNumero($('#nit').val()) && getNitLength() >= 8) {
                        $('#nit').val(calcularDigitoVerificacion($('#nit' ).val()));
                    } else {
                        $('#nit').val('');
                    }
                });
            });
            
            function getNitLength() {
              return $('#nit').val().length;
            }
 
            function validarSiNumero(numero){
                if(!/^([0-9])*$/.test(numero)) {
                    alert("El valor "+numero+" no es un número");
                    return false;
                } else {
                    return true;
                }
            }            
            
            function calcularDigitoVerificacion(nit) {
                console.log("Entro a  la funcion");
                var sumatoria, digitoNit, longitudNit, DV;
                var arregloPrimos=[];               
                
                //procedimiento
                sumatoria = 0;
                digitoNit = 0;
                longitudNit = nit.length;
                arregloPrimos[1] = 3;
                arregloPrimos[2] = 7;
                arregloPrimos[3] = 13;
                arregloPrimos[4] = 17;
                arregloPrimos[5] = 19;
                arregloPrimos[6] = 23;
                arregloPrimos[7] = 29;
                arregloPrimos[8] = 37;
                arregloPrimos[9] = 41;
                arregloPrimos[10] = 43;
                arregloPrimos[11] = 47;
                arregloPrimos[12] = 53;
                arregloPrimos[13] = 59;
                arregloPrimos[14] = 67;
                arregloPrimos[15] = 71;
                
                console.log("Longitud Nit="+longitudNit);

                for (i = 0; i < longitudNit; i++)
                {
                    digitoNit = (nit.substr(i, 1));
                    sumatoria += (digitoNit * arregloPrimos[longitudNit - i]);
                    console.log("i="+i+" DigitoNit="+digitoNit+" Sumatoria="+sumatoria);
                }

                var modulo = sumatoria % 11;

                if (modulo > 1) {
                    DV = 11 - modulo;
                    return  nit+'-'+DV;
                } else {
                    DV = modulo;
                    return   nit+'-'+DV;
                }
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <label>Nit: </label>
        <input type="text" name"nit"  id="nit" placeholder ="Escribe el Nit"  >
    </body>
</html>
```

Según el comportamiento / experiencia de usuario, quizás pueda ser más interesante escuchar otro tipo de evento, como un `keydown` o similar, para evitar que el usuario tenga que hacer click fuera para que se dispare el evento de cambio.

Si tienes alguna duda puedes utilizar los comentarios.

Comment: He intentado eso pero cuando guardo y lo pruebo en el navegador se me borra el campo y la verdad no tengo idea porque pasa eso

Comment: @MauricioCastro, seguramente no colocaste todo el código relevante. Tal vez el formulario se está procesando independientemente de la validación y, lo más seguro, es que se esté recargando la página. Por favor edita la pregunta para aclarar detalles como este.

Comment: @MauricioCastro puedes probar directamente en la respuesta, ya que el ejemplo está basado en tu código y es autoejecutable. Lo que tienes que hacer es introducir al menos una longitud de 8 (que es lo que indicabas en tu pregunta) y pinchar fuera para que se lance el evento que tienes de cambio (`.change` sobre el campo `#nit`). Si es menos de 8, te deja el campo vacío. ¿Es eso a lo que te refieres?

Answer (score 0):

yo uso esto para verificar que  un correo cumpla con el formato de un correo, en la parte final especificas lo del .com que tiene que ser 2 o 3 letras de la A a la Z igual cambiandolo puedes comprobar si es un numero de entre 8 cifras y 8 cifras

```
const pattern = /^[^ ]+@[^ ]+\.[0-9]{8,8}$/
```